# Cause of the phantom issue - classRef is not a constructor

Tags: angular, git, visual-studio-code, npm

I had an issue recently, the app was not loafing in the Browser, when running Angular NX project locally with
`"start-dev": "nx run-many --target=serve --all"`. The screen got stuck on our loading animation which means Angular was not bootstrapped. This error was visible in the console:

```
TypeError: classRef is not a constructor
```

It was basically untraceable, pointing to some <s>Angular.js</s> **bootstrap.ts** file and nothing else.

After some investigation I called it a **Phantom issue** because:

- build was running without errors (local and Jenkins)
- app deployed to the test env was working, issue was not visible
- it was happening on all the branches I checked out
- it was happening in both Safari and Firefox (incognito too)
- none of my colleagues reported it on their computers, on the same branches

What I did and but it didn't help:

- restarted VS Code
- deleted and reinstalled node_modules
- cleared git cache: `git rm -r --cached .`

**I "fixed" it by cloning the project repository again.** Any idea what could be causing this? Before doing that, I forgot to try and clear **npm cache**. Not sure if it would help though.

I would like to know how can it happen. If you ever encountered something similar, is there some other solution than cloning? Can it be caused by some project settings, or is it most likely related to **VS CODE, npm, git** trio?